# Data Upload feature for End Users on RShiny/ Tableau public/ PowerBi or Plotly

Tags: shiny, powerbi, plotly, tableau-api, plotly-dash

I want to design an interactive & dynamic dashboard using **RShiny**, **Tableau public**, **PowerBi** or **Plotly**.
But the crucial feature for me is to place an upload button in the Dashboard in order to let the End User upload his own data and reflect output (plots) in it

Also, I am open to any other solution. For example, I was thinking about designing a Jupyter notebook on Google Collab, but since it's less user-friendly for non-technical users that's why I prefer RShiny, Tableau public, PowerBI or Plotly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no options to add a upload button or any feature in Power BI and also in Tableau, but i guess in Rshiny You can use the default fileInput and style-away the text input element used to show the filename.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Select a file")  
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  runjs("$('#file').parent().parent().siblings().removeClass('form-control').attr('hidden','true');")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```